# Marginal likelihood for a half-normal posterior?

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, likelihood, gaussian-process, marginal-distribution

So I know if we have a normal likelihood $P(\mathbf{y|b}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{Gb}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_y)$ and a normal prior $P(\mathbf{b}|\mathbf{\theta}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{b} | \mu_p, \mathbf{\Sigma}_p)$ specified by some hyperparameters $\theta$, then the marginal likelihood is given by
$$
P(\mathbf{y}|\theta) = \int P(\mathbf{y|b}) P(\mathbf{b}|\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{b} = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{G}\mu_p, \mathbf{G} \mathbf{\Sigma}_p \mathbf{G}^\top + \mathbf{\Sigma}_y)
$$

However, if we additionally know that $b_i \ge 0 \; \forall \; i$, we may instead want to use a half-normal prior where
$$
P(\mathbf{b}|\mathbf{\theta}) =
  \begin{cases}
    2^{m}\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{b} | \mu_p, \mathbf{\Sigma}_p)       & \quad \text{if } b_i \ge 0 \; \forall \; i\\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise}\\
  \end{cases}
$$
where $m$ is the length of $\mathbf{b}$. I want to be able to calculate the marginal likelihood in the case of a half-normal prior like this. We can write down an expression for it just by changing the domain of the integral to $[0 , \infty]$ such that
$$
P(\mathbf{y}|\theta) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(\mathbf{y|b}) P(\mathbf{b}|\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{b} = \; ?
$$
Is there any analytical solution for the above? If not, does anyone have suggestions for how I might go about evaluating it?

Comment: that isn't the correct density for a half-normal prior. you have to double the height.

Comment: @Taylor quite right! infact, wouldn't we need to multiply by 2 to the power of the number of elements in $b$?

Comment: right. I was thinking univariate